# How I can send value in PHP from one page to another using other than session?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have multistep form in which on second step i have date input field and next and previous button.I want to fetch values from the database in 3 step by using date input field but i am clicking on next button not submit button.

This is my second step.

```
  <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
  <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
  <input type="button" name="nextnew" id="nextnew" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
```

I have used ajax.

```
 <script>
       $("#nextnew").click(function() {

             var name2 = $("#date").val();
               //alert(name2);

             $.ajax({
             url:"getuser.php",
            type:"GET",
            data:{ id2: name2},
            success:function(data){
            $("#detail").html(data);
               }
              });
        });  
</script>
```

This is my getuser.php

```
 <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:30px;" id="detail">
 <?php

 include('config.php');
   session_start();  
   if(isset($_REQUEST['id2']))
  {

   $_SESSION['new22']=$_GET['id2'];
   echo "Your Date Selected :-"; echo $_GET['id2'];

   }

 ?>
</div>
```

I am setting value in session value to fetch value in third step.But my problem is that it will have same value as we set it once and it is fetching the same value always.Is there any way to send value from getuser.php to another page.

Comment: use post form for each three and when data is submitted current page data will be add to previous post data.easy

Comment: Problem is that i have date input field on 2 step and on 3 i am fetching value from database by using that date.@Anant.

Comment: Use same form & try to jQuery for next & previous.

Comment: That's an extremely long-winded way of doing an Ajax request; you can do it with two lines...

Comment: How Can I do that.I want to set value other that using session variable.@cybermonkey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should a value in hidden fields.

Comment: use jquery to update a hidden filed and take value from third step you have ajax in third step

Comment: I agree. An easy solution would be to add whatever value you wish to send to the following page as a hidden field in the form.

Comment: Explain with code.I have all steps in same page.and ajax code also.

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="date_next" id="date_next" value="" />

Comment: Please add this on this function: $("#nextnew").click(function(){}

Comment: I have used this but i am not clicking on submit button.How can i get value using $_POST[].

Comment: Please add your brain if this is in ajax... but it should be on hidden field...that is all :)

Comment: It will set value in the hidden field but i will get that value.

Comment: if everything is okay then you get value

Answer (score 0):

**The values can be send to multiple pages through url using PHP and JAVASCRIPT.**

**first.php**

Passing first value to next page **second.php** through url.

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="button"  value="NEXT" onclick="myFunction()" />


<script>
function myFunction() 
{

var a= document.getElementById('name').value;
location.href ="second.php?var1="+a;

}
</script>
```

**second.php**

Now getting the value from first page using PHP **$_GET** .Then pass this value and second value to **third.php** through url.

```
<input type="date" id="name">
<a href="first.php"><input type="button"  value="BACK" /></a>
<input type="button" value="NEXT" onclick="myFunction()" />


<script>
function myFunction() 
{

var a= document.getElementById('name').value;
var b= "<?php $a=$_GET['var1']; echo $a; ?>";
location.href = "third.php?name="+b+"&date="+a;

}
</script>
```

**third.php**

```
<?php

$name=$_GET['name'];
$date=$_GET['date'];
echo  $name;
echo $date;

?>
```